# a broken image, cant open it in php, how to resolve it? imagecreatefromjpeg():Unsupported marker type 0x22

Tags: php, debugging, imagick, gd2, gmagick

maybe a broken image, it cant open in php.

but it is work in web, emm, any browser.

it work in photoshop and image viewer also.

please ask it,

1,how to do can be make it work in php also?

2,if cant resolve it, how to hidden error message?

```
imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 13 extraneous bytes before marker 0x22
Unsupported marker type 0x22

//my coode, even i wanna try to hidden error message, it is cant.
try {
    error_reporting(0);            
    ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
    imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
}(\Exception $e) {

}
```

try to resolve:

1. rename with different suffix: `jpg`, `jpeg`, `gif`, `png`.
2. run on different environment: `linux`, `windows`, `php5.6`, `php7.1`.
3. run on different library: `gd2`, `imagick`, `gmagick`.

still cant resolved.
please help me.

this is the pic:

[image]

Comment: If you think this could be a bug in PHP itself, you should put it into the PHP bugtracker. Otherwise, clarify your question please

Comment: It seems that imgur.com agrees with php: It is not a valid image.

Comment: And how did you conclude that it isn't the image that actually _is_ corrupt?

Comment: @jeroen maybe it is not a valid image, but it can be show on web right? it can be open in photoshop and picture viewer also. so i think it, it is able to  open in php also

Comment: Some software can actually fix some issues on the fly. Specially more advanced image software.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson im not sure. maybe it is corrupt image.

Comment: I would suggest that you check that out before blaming PHP. :-) Either way, if there _is_ a bug in PHP, then SO isn't the place to report it.

Comment: @NicoHaase, yes. i have modify the question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have change the question and modify content. im just looking for a way to resolve it. not any popurse to blaming php. im sorry.

Comment: What do you mean? When I open the link you posted I get a message the the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors. So no, it cannot be displayed on the web.

Comment: @jeroen it is work here. no any problem.  i have try IE, chrome. yes, it is not   work in firefox. but if you right click on the image and save it. it is work in image viewer.

Comment: Again, different software handles corrupt images differently. Some software can fix (or ignore) the issue. Some software doesn't. If it doesn't work using multiple software (like you state: some browsers, PHP GD etc.), then the image is most likely the issue and there's nothing we can do about it here.

Comment: Don't use that kind of language. It's not appropriate here (no matter the context). I don't have any other fix than open it in Photoshop, re-save it and use the new file instead. A super quick google on the issue, this is an issue with `libjeg`, which many software uses.